# PHP Ajax response parsererror

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call and return a response. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to get at the response. Here is my javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "inc.test.php", 
    data: {list:postData},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        if(response.success == 1){
            alert (response.testdata);
            }},
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown); 
        console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Here is my inc.test.php code sending the json data back:

```
if($result)
    {
    $arr=array(
        "success" => 1,
        "testdata" => 'Testing');
    echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

In my Console/Response I see this:

```
{"success":1,"testdata":"Testing"}
```

I've read tons of articles and can't seem to figure out whats going on. Please help!

Comment: Are you getting an error or are you just looking to deal with the response?

Comment: inspect the actual request response body in dev tools network and see if there are other characters being returned other than the json

Answer (score 1):

```js
success: function(response) {
  var resp = JSON.parse(response);
  // rest of code ...
  }
```

May be because you have to parse your code? You didn't specify what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using PHP's `trim()` function before sending the data? i think you have an extra space when you `json_encode` or use `trim()`.

```
if($result)
    {
    $arr=array(
        "success" => 1, 
                    ^
        "testdata" => 'Testing');
                     ^
    echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't matter, it's an array declaration so you can have tabs and spaces there to format the code for readability.

Answer (score 0):

if this is in wordpress , you may forgot to

```
wp_die();
```

in the end of php function called by ajax request